# node child_process spawn gives error code -2 ENEONT

Tags: javascript, node.js

im trying to make an npx command where i can run child commands inside

my package.json bin:

```json
"bin": {
    "malzahar": "./src/bin/malzahar.js"
},
```

here is my `malzahar.js` code:

```js
#! /usr/bin/env node

import cp from 'child_process'
import yargs from 'yargs'

const argv = yargs(process.argv).argv
const command = argv._[2]

if (command == 'dev') {
    // this works
    cp.exec('babel-node ./node_modules/malzahar/src/entries/server.js')

    // this gives error -2 ENOENT
    cp.spawn('babel-node ./node_modules/malzahar/src/entries/server.js')
        .on('error', function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

the `server.js` file just starts a basic express server:

```js
import express from 'express'

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

i can get it to work when using `exec`, but it doesn't output `Example app listening on port 3000` in the terminal

i read that it might work using `spawn`, but when i use `spawn` it gives me error code -2 ENEONT:

```
Error: spawn babel-node ./node_modules/malzahar/src/entries/server.js ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn babel-node ./node_modules/malzahar/src/entries/server.js',
  path: 'babel-node ./node_modules/malzahar/src/entries/server.js',
  spawnargs: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `exec` is a listener too

I got it to work using this:

```js
    const child = cp.exec('babel-node ./node_modules/malzahar/src/entries/server.js')

    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    })
```